# Nsubstitute or moq an Async method so it will return a faulted task instead of exception

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In the below code for each request we are calling rest client in an Async manner. Rest client is basically a http client which is calling some webapis in a batch. If suppose AsyncTaskCount value is 5 then 5 request will be called asynchronously and then in the while block we are getting the result for each call. If any response out of those 5 request has an exception then the response will be faulted and IsFaulted becomes true for that particular request and in the response we can get the inner exception.

```
private async Task<List<RequestResponse>> ProcessInvestment(List<Request> Requests, List<Result> Results, ILogger log)
    {

        var requestResponses = new List<RequestResponse>();
        var asyncTaskCount = Convert.ToInt32(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AsyncTaskCount"));
        log.LogInformation($"Start processing {Requests.Count} in batches of {asyncTaskCount}");

        for (int index = 0; index < Requests.Count; index = index + asyncTaskCount)
        {
            var requestBatch = Requests.Skip(index).Take(asyncTaskCount).ToList();

            var requests = requestBatch.Select(x => _restClient.RequestResponse(x)).ToList();

            while (requests.Count > 0)
            {
                // Identify the first task that completes.
                Task<RequestResponse> requestResponseTask = await Task.WhenAny(requests);
                var requestResponse = new RequestResponse();

                // ***Remove the selected task from the list so that you don't process it more than once
                requests.Remove(requestResponseTask);

                if (!requestResponseTask.IsFaulted)
                {
                    // Await the completed task.
                    requestResponse = await requestResponseTask;
                    requestResponses.Add(requestResponse);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (requestResponseTask.Exception.InnerException != null && requestResponseTask.Exception.InnerException is Exception)
                    {
                        var result = new Result();
                        result = ResponseTransformComponent.ResponseToResult(((Exception)requestResponseTask.Exception.InnerException).Request, null);
                        result.SetBadRequestErrorDetails(((Exception)RequestResponseTask.Exception.InnerException).BadRequestResponse);
                        results.Add(Result);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw requestResponseTask.Exception;
                    }
                }
            }

            log.LogInformation($"Number of records processed = {requestResponses.Count}");
        }

        log.LogInformation($"Total invalid and Bad requests count = {results.Count}");
        return RequestResponses;
    }
```

Below is the code for restclient which is called from the above method.

```
public async Task<Response> RequestResponse(Request request)
        {
            var response = await GetDataFromService("calculation", "CalculateCapital", request);

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response);
        }

public async Task<string> GetDataFromService(string controller, string method, object request)
        {
            var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(ServiceEnum.DCS);

            string baseAddress = client.BaseAddress.ToString();

            var requestUrl = $"api/{controller}/{method}";
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                {
                    throw new CalculatorServiceException("Bad Request", JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BadRequestResponse>(responseResult), (Request)request);
                }

                throw new Exception($"Status code: {response.StatusCode}. {responseResult}");
            }

            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
```

GetDataFromService method is called from Calculate method. And GetDataFromService method will return a custom exception if the request is a Bad Request.

I am trying to write the unit test case for the above method and try to mock a request so that it will return a faulted task and then IsFaulted should become true. Below is the part of my unit test case.

```
 _restClient
                .When(a => a.RequestResponse(Arg.Any<Request>()))
                .Do(a => {Task.FromException(new CalculatorServiceException(string.Empty, new BadRequestResponse { Message = string.Empty, ModelState = new Dictionary<string, string[]> { { "CalculationDates.StartDate", new string[] { "0002: Duration too short to execute calculations (CalculationDates.StartDate)" } } } }, Arg.Any<Request>())); });
```

If i mock my restclient method like above then it is throwing the exception instead of giving the response with IsFaulted to true. So how should i mock the restclient method so that it will return a faulted task which has an exception instead of throwing it. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`When..Do` is for wiring up [callbacks](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/callbacks/) for when a member is called.

Try using [`Returns`](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-from-function/) instead:

```
_restClient.RequestResponse(Arg.Any<Request>())
           .Returns(x => Task.FromException<RequestResponse>(...));

// (assuming RequestResponse(..) returns a Task<RequestResponse>. Tweak as required)
```

Comment: Thans David for the response. I have added some more information in the question part which is having the implementation of restclient method, to give you more insights. Because when i tried with the suggestion you provided, I am getting below error.  One or more errors occurred. (Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]' to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Rabobank.Beleggen.DoelmonitorServices.RestClient.Entities.RequestResponse]'.)

Comment: @nishantmittal You need to return the correct type of task. If you need a `Task<T>` rather than a `Task` (void result), then try `Task.FromException<T>` where `T` is whatever type you require. I've updated the answer to reflect this (although you may need to tweak the value of `T` for your use case).

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar issue with a different cause so I'm gonna leave this here in case someone finds this information useful.

In my code, I create multiple `Tasks` that are started and added to an array (something like this):

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task<Result>>();
tasks.Add(someService.GetResult1());
tasks.Add(someService.GetResult2());
tasks.Add(someService.GetResult3());

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

if (tasks.Any(x => x.IsFaulted))
    // handle error ...
```

Contrary to what the code in the question does, I don't use a `while`-loop and check the state of the `Tasks`. Instead I use `Task.WhenAll()` to wait for the `Tasks` to complete.

Now notice that this is an `async` method and I `await` it. This means all the `Tasks` in the list are awaited too.

`Tasks` behave differently when it comes to throwing `Exceptions` depending on whether they are awaited or not.

- If a task is *not awaited*, e.g. by using a `while`-loop and checking the state, any exception that is thrown will be swallowed. After the task is completed we can see that there was an `Exception` because `task.IsFaulted` is `true`
- If we `await` a `Task` on the other hand, any `Exception` that is thrown inside of the `Task` is thrown to the calling context. This means we need to handle the `Exception`!

So in my case my code should look like this instead:

```cs
var tasks = var tasks = new List<Task<Result>>();
tasks.Add(someService.GetResult());
tasks.Add(someService.GetResult());
tasks.Add(someService.GetResult());

try
{
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // handle error ...
}
```

In my test, I can set up the response like David explained in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61946303/10069673) and the `Exception` will be thrown, because I `await` the `Task`.